# Can you force add an ignored file type in Perforce?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm currently using the `P4IGNORE` environment variable. I mainly use this alongside the P4VS Extension so that my premake generated projects and solutions do not get added to perforce.

I recently upgraded my P4V client and when I try to manually add a file with an extension that is in my `p4ignore.txt` file it does not get added to my pending changelist (this did not happen before with the older version of P4V I had installed).

Is there a way to force add the files even if their extensions are in my `p4ignore.txt` file?

Comment: I'm confused: do you want files with this extension ignored? Or do you want to be able to add files with this extension? Or is it more complicated: sometimes you want to be able to add them, but sometimes you want Perforce to ignore them?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I want them ignored in Visual Studio, but when I am using the P4V client I want to be able to drag and drop files and open them for add even if the extension is in my p4ignore file. By command line you are able to do this with the -I flag. Ex: `p4 add -I D:\helloworld.txt`. This would add the helloworld.txt file to your pending changelist even if the .txt extension is in your p4ignore file.

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure about P4V, but you can do this using the P4 command line client.

From the 'p4 add' notes in the Perforce Command Reference:

By default, p4 add skips over files mentioned in any applicable P4IGNORE
  files. To override this behavior, use the `-I` option to ignore the
  contents of any P4IGNORE files.